# Search ComboBox's ValueMembers for a value

Tags: vb.net, combobox, indexing, find, key-value

I have a ComboBox (myCombo) with following features:

```
Index     ValueMember     DisplayMember
 0           11             A
 1           34             H
 2           36             J
 3           85             W
 4           99             M
```

I want to find the index of a ValueMember in the ComboBox.

myCombo.FindString() searches within the DisplayMembers, But i want to search within the ValueMembers.

Answer (score 1):

Lets pretend that Items in your combo are of unanimous type. Sorry for c# but it is really close to VB

Setup your combo in constructor:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new { Name = "a", Val = 35 });
comboBox1.Items.Add(new { Name = "b", Val = 30 });
comboBox1.Items.Add(new { Name = "c", Val = 256 });
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Val";
comboBox1.DisplayMember  = "Name";
```

Then, on click I am looking for an index of item with value 256:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((int)comboBox1.Items[i].GetType().GetProperty("Val").GetValue(comboBox1.Items[i]) = 256)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("index: " + i.ToString());
        }
    }

 }
```

Here I am using reflection to get the value of the property of unanimous type. If you know the type of the object you use - it even easier - use DirectCast (this is VB):

```
If DirectCast(comboBox1.Items(i), <known_type>).Val = 256 Then...
```

Main thing here is that in this line, I get the item property and get its value and compare to supplied value (in VB):

```
CInt(comboBox1.Items(i).GetType().GetProperty("Val").GetValue(comboBox1.Items(i))) = <your int value>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(For index = 0 To comboBox1.Items.Count - 1
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index
            Dim dr As DataRowView = TryCast(Me.BindingContext(comboBox1.DataSource).Current, DataRowView)
            If dr(1).ToString() = "your Value" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next)
```